# In XAML, How to call a function in timer, if it's input and output are bound to different objects?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, timer

I want to move a small ellipse on a canvas, according to a function (Lissagous) with a time variable. There are 2 sliders which should change the horizontal and vertical amplitudes of the function and the function itself should be called in timer tick (and this is actually the problem). I successfully managed the binding for slider values + function arguments (using `ObjectDataProvider` tag in XAML) and I also did the binding for output of the function + the coordinates of the ellipse on the canvas using `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`.
The problem is, as far as I understood, this binding (for both input and output) works only when user changes the slider. It means that if I call that function in a timer, it generates new numbers per tick, but it does not change the position of the ellipse on the canvas. but if user moves the slider, the ellipse moves on  the canvas accordingly, regardless of the change of the t. Am I expecting too much? Did I somehow limited output of the function? If so, what should I do to call the function to move the ellipse whether the slider is being changed or not.
Here is the most part of my XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="lissagousX"
        ObjectType="{x:Type LissagousXAML:Lissagous}" MethodName="LissFuncX">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <system:Double>1</system:Double>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="lissagousY"
        ObjectType="{x:Type LissagousXAML:Lissagous}" MethodName="LissFuncY">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <system:Double>1</system:Double>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

here is slider-->input binding

```
<Slider 
    Width="200" 
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="50"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource lissagousX},
                            Path=MethodParameters[0],
                            BindsDirectlyToSource=True,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Slider 
    Width="200" 
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="50"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource lissagousY},
                            Path=MethodParameters[0],
                            BindsDirectlyToSource=True,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and here is output-->Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top binding

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="White">
        <Ellipse Fill="Black" Height="10" Width="10"
                 Canvas.Left="{Binding Source={StaticResource lissagousX}}"
                 Canvas.Top="{Binding Source={StaticResource lissagousY}}" />
</Canvas>
```

In the mainwindow I have one extra class `public class Lissagous` consists of 2 methods:

```
public double LissFuncX(double A)

public double LissFuncY(double B)
```

---

**EDITED: I need to manage this concept only by using pure BINDING and no event handlers.**

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you bind your UI to properties in a view model, which could look like shown below. The variable names correspond to those used in the Wikipedia article about [Lissajous Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).

```
public class LissajousViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    public double a { get; set; }
    public double b { get; set; }
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        var t = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
        X = A * Math.Sin(a * t);
        Y = B * Math.Cos(b * t);
        RaisePropertyChanged("X");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Y");
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you might bind to the view model properties like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas Margin="200">
        <Ellipse Fill="Black" Height="10" Width="10"
                 Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" />
    </Canvas>

    <Slider Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100"
            Minimum="50" Maximum="200" Value="{Binding A}"/>
    <Slider Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Height="100"
            Minimum="50" Maximum="200" Value="{Binding B}"/>
</Grid>
```

The view model might be updated by a `DispatcherTimer` callback like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new LissajousViewModel
    {
        a = 1,
        b = 1.5,
        A = 100,
        B = 100
    };

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20),
        IsEnabled = true
    };

    timer.Tick += (s, e) => viewModel.Update();

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Clemens, your code works very neatly. I appreciate it very much. But I would be grateful if you could somehow show me my mistakes, tell me why it is not working or maybe tell me how I can change it. This way I will learn more!
I just edited my code. Sorry that I did not underline this point that I need to do it using BINDING and no HANDLERs :(

Comment: The core idea is that data binding works with properties (and not so well with methods), and that there is a common architectural pattern, called MVVM, which helps you with separating the layers of your application. A good starting point for further reading is the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.